# Quick AsyncTask doInBackgroun Q

Tags: android

Say I am running

```
new CommentList().execute(url);
```

If I am in the doInBackground method and I catch a Null value and inside that null value exception I try running the same one again:

```
new CommentList().execute(url);
```

Will it stop running the first one?

Can I do this:

```
if (result == null) {
    cancel(true);                           
    }

@Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        new CommentList().execute(commentlinkurl);
    }
```

Basically I don't want the onPostExecute to run if it gets cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good idea. You should not be creating new task on a non-UI thread (from within `doInBackground` method).

From [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> There are a few threading rules that must be
>   followed for this class to work properly:
>
> - **The task instance must be created on the UI thread.**
> - **execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.**
> - Do not call onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually.
> - The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

**Edit based on comments:**
You can however start the task again inside `onPostExecute` or `onCancelled` method. You can simply return some specific result to it from `doInBackground` or save your Throwable in the AsyncTask member variable to analyze it further:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Something something) {
    if(something == null){
        // safe to start new execute task here
    }
    // or
    if(mException instanceof TemporaryIssueException){
        // safe to start new execute task here
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but possibly returning a relevant result to `onPostExecute(...)` and creating a new instance and executing from there would be OK.

Comment: onCancelled also runs on UI thread so it should be fine to start a new task in it.

Comment: Calling 'cancel' will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. Calling this method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked.

Comment: Is OnCancelled() on the UI thread? If not, how do I jump to my onPostExecute when I catch the null?

Comment: Hmm so if I catch the null right before it happens in doInBackground then doInBackground will continue on though?